# Dynamic Delivery Failed to bind to the service

Tags: android, gradle, dynamic, module

I'm trying to use Dynamic Delivery inside my application. 
I've followed this Google code lab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery/index.html#7, however I'm getting some errors.

**Gradlew build error**
In the terminal, when I add the following command: `./gradlew build` I get the following error message when running in emulator:

```
app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

When running in an actual device I get this error:

```
Split Install Error(-2): A requested module is not available (to this user/device, for the installed apk)
```

**Runtime error**
When I run the application, and get the following error:

```
 com.google.android.play.core.internal.aa: Failed to bind to the service
```

The previous error corresponds to the following code:

```
val mManager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this)
val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
            .addModule(view.context.getString(R.string.module_qrscan))
            .build()

        mManager.startInstall(request)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) qrScanModuleInstallationMutableLiveData.value = Result.Success(true)
                else {
                    Log.d("QRModule",  "The error is: ${it.exception}")
                    qrScanModuleInstallationMutableLiveData.value = Result.Error(it.exception)
                }
            }
```

This is the following gradle file from my dynamic feature module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSDK

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tafies.qrscan"
        minSdkVersion versions.minSDK
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSDK
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Required for AR because it includes a library built with Java 8
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

And this is the following gradle file from my `:app` module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' // For Firebase Performance Monitoring
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android' // For Dokka documentation
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // For Crashlytics

// For version name and version code
ext.versionMajor = 1
ext.versionMinor = 2
ext.versionPatch = 1
ext.versionClassifier = null // Indicate if we're classifying the versions for development
ext.isSnapshot = true // Means that the app is in development mode
ext.isAlpha = false // Means that the app is in it's primary testing phase
ext.isBeta = false // Means that the app is in it's secondary testing phase
ext.isRC = false // Means that the app is in release candidate
ext.minimumSdkVersion = 21

android {
    compileSdkVersion versions.compileSDK

    // Enable data binding
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    bundle {
        density {
            // Different APKs are generated for devices with different screen densities; true by default.
            enableSplit true
        }
        abi {
            // Different APKs are generated for devices with different CPU architectures; true by default.
            enableSplit true
        }
        language {
            // This is disabled so that the App Bundle does NOT split the APK for each language.
            // We're gonna use the same APK for all languages.
            enableSplit false
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tafies.events"
        minSdkVersion versions.minSDK
        targetSdkVersion versions.targetSDK
        versionCode generateVersionCode()
        versionName generateVersionName()

        buildConfigField "String", "ALGOLIA_CLIENT_ID", "\"${project.property("algolia_app_id")}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ALGOLIA_SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY", "\"${project.property("algolia_search_only_api_key")}\""
        buildConfigField "String", "STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY", "\"${project.property("stripe_publishable_key")}\""

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // For testing release mode
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug // TODO remove this line
//            debuggable true // TODO remove this line

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
//            shrinkResources true TODO remove the comment

            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
//            minifyEnabled true TODO remove the comment

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            FirebasePerformance {
                // Set this flag to 'false' to disable @AddTrace annotation processing and
                // automatic HTTP/S network request monitoring
                // for a specific build variant at compile time.
                instrumentationEnabled false
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    dynamicFeatures = [':qrScan']
}

// Generate version code
private Integer generateVersionCode() {
    return ext.minimumSdkVersion * 10000000 + ext.versionMajor * 10000 + ext.versionMinor * 100 + ext.versionPatch
}

// Generate version name
private String generateVersionName() {
    String versionName = "${ext.versionMajor}.${ext.versionMinor}.${ext.versionPatch}"
    if (!ext.versionClassifier) {
        if (ext.isSnapshot) {
            ext.versionClassifier = "SNAPSHOT"
        } else if (ext.isAlpha) {
            ext.versionClassifier = "ALPHA"
        } else if (ext.isBeta) {
            ext.versionClassifier = "BETA"
        } else if (ext.isRC) {
            ext.versionClassifier = "RC"
        }
    }

    if (ext.versionClassifier) {
        versionName += "-" + ext.versionClassifier
    }

    return versionName
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    .... more libraries
}

kotlin {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: no I haven't  :(

Comment: still no solution? :"

Comment: @AndreaLk I was not able to find a solution